# Deleted question appears on review queue

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, reviewing, deleted-questions

I was recently (in fact just right now) browsing the review queue when I saw an off-topic question. I tried to downvote, but then I got a message that the question was deleted and I couldn't vote on it.

I believe this is a bug. If it isn't then please correct me, but I don't see a reason for a deleted question to be reviewed.

---

Edit: I just read about [review audits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/157121/what-are-review-tests-audits-and-how-do-they-work), but they aren't even active on here, so it couldn't be that either.

Comment: This would be a lot easier to investigate if you linked to the review or at least the question you were reviewing.

Comment: @Dennis I didn't know you could link to reviews. Will do next time I ask a question like this.

Answer (score 2):

This was most likely just bad timing.

I assume the question you were reviewing is [What date encoding could this be?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/178464/what-date-encoding-could-this-be).

- It was asked at 10:57:13 UTC.
- It entered the review queue at 11:00:01 UTC.
- It was deleted 11:12:35 UTC.
- It left the review queue at 11:14:53 UTC.

So the question was removed from the review queue because it was deleted, it just happened with a delay of 2 minutes and 18 seconds.

Comment: Yep, that is what I was reviewing.